# Pythonic way to count if a value is 'NaN' in a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a dictionary of dictionaries with several values. I want to count all the entries that do not contain 'NaN' (Not a Number in a string).

```
for each in enron_data:
    if enron_data[each]["salary"] !='NaN':
        counter += 1

    if enron_data[each]['email_address']!='NaN':
        valid_email +=1
```

I'm not familiar with list comprehensions, but I'm pretty sure there's might be a more pythonic way to achieve this.

Can anyone share pythonic advice?

Thank you

Comment: `counter = sum(enron_data[each]["salary"] != 'NaN' for each in enron_data)`

Comment: Use `pandas` and use `df.isnull().sum()`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want this to use a comprehension, you need to get the `sum` of each `each` in `enron_data`, where `each`s salary is not `'NaN'`. As highlighted by the word exercise, you should notice that `each` is probably not the best variable name for this. Take the following example:

> you need to get the `sum` of each `boat` in `boats`, where the `boat`s cost is not `'NaN'`.

Which is easier to read. With Python it's the same, and is why good variable names are advised.

And so you'd want to do:

```
counter += sum(enron_data[each]["salary"] !='NaN' for each in enron_data)
valid_email += sum(enron_data[each]["email_address"] !='NaN' for each in enron_data)
```

If `enron_data` has a function like `dict.values`, or better `dict.itervalues`, then you'd want to use that instead. The latter one is simply a version of the former with better memory usage.

And so you could instead use:

```
counter += sum(each["salary"] !='NaN' for each in enron_data.itervalues())
valid_email += sum(each["email_address"] !='NaN' for each in enron_data.itervalues())
```

---

I don't think this approach is that much better than your current, but you could make it a function, to reduce code duplication, but whether it's better ultimately comes down to how you're using it.

But it's definitely better than the answer you provided. There's no need to create a new dictionary, it changes memory usage from \$O(1)\$ to \$O(n)\$, is harder to read, and is slower, as it requires more effort to create a dictionary, then to sum booleans.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is the following:

```
how_many = len(dict((key, value) for key, value in enron_data.items() if value["salary"] == 'NaN'))
```

I had a classmate explain it to me. Suggested answer in the comment sections above don't meet the requirements.